# How can i use custom model permissions to check before displaying a viewset?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm quite new to Django rest framework and are struggling to use the custom model permissions to check if a user is allowed to access a certain endpoint.

Whenever trying to access the endpoint i get the "You are not authorized to perform this action" message even though the user is a superuser and/or has been given all app permissions both to the group and/or user.

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    User model which inherits AbstractBaseuser. AbstractBaseUser provides the 
    core implementation of a user model.
    """

    email = models.EmailField(
        _('email address'),
        unique=True,
    )
    ...

    class Meta:
        ...
        permissions = (
            ('has_users_list', 'Can list users'),
        )
```

Permissions.py

```
class UserOrGroupPermission(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        user_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        group_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(group__user=request.user)

        # get required permissions variable from view
        required_permissions_mapping = getattr(view, 'required_permissions', {})
        # determine if the required permissions for the particular request method
        required_permissions = required_permissions_mapping.get(request.method, [])

        if user_permissions or group_permissions in required_permissions:
            return True
```

Viewsets.py

```
class UsersListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = UsersSerializer
    permission_classes = [UserOrGroupPermission]
    required_permissions = {
        'GET': ['has_users_list']
    }
```

Comment: Try following, class UsersListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated| UserOrGroupPermission]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superusers have all permissions implicitly, which means they necessarily do not have these permissions explicitly assigned to them in the `Permission` table. And so you should use `if user.is_superuser` to check that he is a superuser.
You also some issues on this line

```
 if user_permissions or group_permissions in required_permissions:
```

The `in` operator takes precedence over the `or` operator, so basically what you're checking is if the user has any permissions at all or the user's group permissions are in the set of required permissions. And also, you're comparing permission objects with a list of permission names.

The following should help:

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return True

    user_permissions = set(Permission.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('codename', flat=True))
    group_permissions = set(Permission.objects.filter(group__user=request.user).values_list('codename', flat=True))


    # get required permissions variable from view
    required_permissions_mapping = getattr(view, 'required_permissions', {})
    # determine if the required permissions for the particular request method
    required_permissions = set(required_permissions_mapping.get(request.method, []))

    if required_permissions.issubset(user_permissions | group_permissions):
        return True
    return False
```

It essentially checks if the required permissions are contained in a union of the two sets of permissions